# Concatenate query params and add them to url

Tags: javascript, angular, string, typescript, angular-httpclient

I have a checkbox of 4 categories (Error, Warning, Info and Debug) and whenever the user check some of them, I have to add them to the query to make an httpclient call.

For example if the user check all of them I should send a query with: (category=eq=Error,category=eq=Warning,category=eq=Info,category=eq=Debug)

That's what I did , I tried to create a string object and concatenate one by one if they are checked :

```
 if (obj.category) {
      const ctgLength = obj.category.length; //the number of categorieschecked by the user
      object["(category=eq"] = obj.category[0];
      for (let i = 1; i < ctgLength - 1; i++) {
      console.log(obj.category[i]);
      object[",category=eq"] = obj.category[i] + ",";
     }
     object["category=eq"] = obj.category[ctgLength - 1] + ")";
   }
```

But what I get is: (category=eq=Error,category=eq=Info,category=eq=Debug)
The for loop affect only the value of the last iteration.

First: is what I'm doing a good way to generate a query in my case ?
Second: How can I fix this code to get all the categories in the query ?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't undestand why you store the number of category in ctgLength.
You can't know what is really checked

Comment: No, I know ! because it is handled with another function so what I have in the category array is only the checked ones, the predeclared array with all of them is called categories in my code :)

Comment: you can do this in on line, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wouldn't something like this work?

```
const combinedCategories = obj.category.map(category => `category=eq=${category}`).join(',');
const combinedCategoriesEnclosedInBrackets = `(${combinedCategories})`
```

Edit: as [@Mkdgs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2365628/mkdgs) mentioned, we can also use `toString()` instead of join as it adds comma by default

```
const combinedCategories = obj.category.map(category => `category=eq=${category}`).toString();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for two things, first: your solution solved my problem, second you made me learn a better way to do it without  prejudjments regarding my coding level :) So thank you so much

Comment: join(',') is not really needed, because toString add comma by default:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString

Answer (score 1):

You do your loop with `let i = 1`
this should be `let i = 0`

Indices in JavaScript are 0-based.

Correct is:

```
for (let i = 0; i < ctgLength; i++) {
```

It looks like you are programming as a VB programmer would.

Index handling in JavaScript is "different" vs. in VB:

var a = [0,1,2];
==> a.length = 3
3 is the actual number of elements in the array

So to loop over all, it's `for(var i =0; i < 3; ++i) console.log(a[i]);`

In VB, you can do

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 4 Step 1
    System.Console.WriteLine(i)
Next i
```

and the equivalent in c-based languages would be

```
for (let i = 0; i <= ctgLength; i++) { console.log(i);}
```

note the <=, not the <.

which is why you need to do the -1 in VB: `For i As Integer = 0 To ctgLength-1 Step 1`.
That -1 is not required in C based languages, since they use < and not <=, otherwise you need to specify <=, then it works, too - although that's adding redundant computations.

Comment: @Boha: That's because you also do ctgLength -1

Comment: What do you mean by "It looks like you program like you would program with VB". If you have a better alternative to solve my case let me know ;)

Comment: yes because I need to put a parentese before the first one and after the last one, that's why I handled them outside of the for loop.

Comment: "var a = [0,1,2];
==> a.length = 3
3 is the actual number of elements in the array So to loop over all, it's for(var i =0; i < 3; ++i) console.log(a[i]);' I KNOW THAT ! But this still have nothing to do with my error :)

Comment: Well, you write you want to get 
(category=eq=Error,category=eq=Warning,category=eq=Info,category=eq=Debug)
but you actually get 
(category=eq=Error,category=eq=Info,category=eq=Debug) 
which is missing the warning, which is probably because warning is the last element, that you skip with your loop where you miss the last element. And the reason map join works is because that does the loop for you, and eliminiates your "ability" to do it wrong.

Comment: yup, the for loop was incorrect because it was missing 1 element

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, please for the love of god define any string literals as constants in a dedicated file. This ensures maintainability and sanity for everyone involved.

```
const Constants = {
  CategoryQueryParam: "category=eq"
};
```

Now lets pull that code into its own function

```
function buildCategoryQueryString (selectedCatergories) {}
```

And refactor the implementation a little.

```
 function buildCategoryQueryString (selectedCatergories: string[]): string {
     if (selectedCatergories == null || selectedCatergories.length === 0) {
         return null;
     }
     let queryString = selectedCatergories.map(category => 
     `${Constants.CategoryQueryParam}=${category}`).join(',');
     return `(${queryString})`;
 }
```

Comment: I did a file for the query constants as you said. I appreciate that you helped to make my code cleaner and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
obj = {};
obj.category = ['woot','foo','bar','42']; // if it's an array 

var yourresult = '('+obj.category.map( str =>  "category=eq="+str )+')';

console.log(yourresult);
```